# Choose Different Screen Layouts with Latest NVIDIA Driver Dual 4K Setup

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 15.04, performance

I just bought a ASUS PB287Q monitor and hooked it up (via HDMI) to my ASUS N550JK-DS521H. Everything works...but the performance of rendering on the external (right) monitor is terrible. So bad I can hardly use my external monitor without getting very frustrated all the time. The experience on the builtin laptop monitor is however perfect as before, strangely when using the virtual configuration; If the window is put the first screen interaction is very snappy - if it gets placed on the second interaction is very sluggish. Same problem even in mirrored mode. Then the rendering happens about 100 ms after the builtin all the time. I'm sensing some software rendering (buffering) problem. Same problem occurs in XFCE. Is the current XServer not up for the job? If so I would really like to try to configure my system to use a separate XScreen on my external monitor.

But...I've tried searching through the dialogs of NVIDIA X Server Settings (`sudo nvidia-settings`) but nowhere can I find any information about how to change the screen configuration. Previously this could be changed by clicking on "Advanced..." in the "X Server Dispaly Configuration". But now nothing happens when I click on it; I would like to try TwinView and running a separate display server on my external monitor. Do I have to hack my xorg.conf to try this out? I thought these annoything text-file configurations where gotten rid of long ago (sigh).

I've tried both the Intel and NVIDIA driver. Same problem.

Both cards are by default configured to use a common virtual screen of size 2*4K (7680x2160).

I'm using NVIDIA driver version 346.59 on Ubuntu release 15.04.

I've installed nvidia-prime.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue might be the HDMI cable. I have a similar setup (ASUS NX500 running Ubuntu 15.10 with NVIDIA 352.41, and my external monitor is an ASUS PB287Q (same as yours)). The only difference is that I'm running the external monitor from the display port, and I get excellent performance out of the external display. When I first bought the ASUS PB287Q and connected it using HDMI I had major lag issues (30 fps external) but that was under Windows 8.1... I switched to display port and it fixed it in windows. When I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 from Windows I never had any issues with performance of the external display.